# Should i install multiple wordpress for one site?

Tags: multisite, subdomains

So i am building a site that will have tech news,articles , how-to plus education section. The problem is education section will have lots of categories and i want to show all those categories on main menu.so i was thinking i should redirect education to a sub domain(i.e user clicks on education in main site and is redirected to a subdomain e.g education.mysite.com )and at that subdomain another wordpress is installed. Do you think this is the right approach?  I thought about using multisite feature but my host provider doesn't support it and also people say it makes it complicated to migrate. 
Looking forward for your solutions .

Comment: Can you explain more about why you think a separate install, or a MultiSite, would be needed? It sounds like you just have 1 site with 1 group of users, but one section may be fairly large. That shouldn't be a problem. You can easily create a CPT for the education section and create whatever taxonomies you need for categories, etc. That way everything is in 1 install, easier to maintain and interlink, and you can use menus to include any and all content. If you break it into multiple sites you'll have to hard-code links into your menus - what if one changes?

Comment: Well if i only work on 1 wordpress than education portion content menu will have to be in sub menu and it will create a mess. Like suppose main wordpress has menu :
Home How-to Reviews News Education
where education further has menu  :
EntryTest Universities Carear Counselling Alevels
and each menu has sub menu
and what if i wanted to change theme of education section too?I think i cant do this in single wordpress installation.

Comment: You can easily create templates specific to Education - its taxonomies, its posts, its archives - and meet all your goals. MultiSite is really geared toward separate sites that have the same basic user base.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use custom post type, that will create another section in wp backend. you can do it your own if you are a programmer or you can use custom post type if you dont know how to program. custom post type plugin will create another post type for your education section and paid version of can provide the template to customise and display the post type in frontend.

Yes multisite is a bit complected approach to meet your requirement and you dont need to install multiple wordpress.

Refer this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) for create custom post type and display on frontend

Comment: Actually, just as important is to create a custom taxonomy for the education categories to keep them separate from the normal post cats.